# Migrated mySQL to a new host with mySQL 8.0.17, unable to update/start mysqld

Tags: mysql

I recently setup a new host with mySQL ver 8.0.17 and moved an old mySQL database (ver 5.1.73) to it using `mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > somefile.sql` and then importing it with `mysql -u root -p < /pathtodatase.sql` . Right now, I am unable to start `mysqld` and am unable to run an update to fix the tables.

I have attempted to run a mysql upgrade as mentioned in the log, but it doesn't seem to help. Initially I ran `mysql_upgrade` but that feature is deprecated so instead I ran `mysqld --upgrade=AUTO` and still am having issues with the service starting up. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the output from `mysqld.log`:

`2020-02-07T01:09:23.054386Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
2020-02-07T01:09:23.056223Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/libexec/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.17) starting as process 1533
2020-02-07T01:09:24.005561Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010727] [Server] System table 'plugin' is expected to be transactional.
2020-02-07T01:09:24.188459Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-02-07T01:09:24.206417Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010929] [Server] Storage engine 'MyISAM' does not support system tables. [mysql.user].
2020-02-07T01:09:24.206431Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010929] [Server] Storage engine 'MyISAM' does not support system tables. [mysql.db].
2020-02-07T01:09:24.206442Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010929] [Server] Storage engine 'MyISAM' does not support system tables. [mysql.tables_priv].
2020-02-07T01:09:24.206466Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010929] [Server] Storage engine 'MyISAM' does not support system tables. [mysql.columns_priv].
2020-02-07T01:09:24.206486Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010929] [Server] Storage engine 'MyISAM' does not support system tables. [mysql.procs_priv].
2020-02-07T01:09:24.206719Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013143] [Server] Column count of mysql.user is wrong. Expected 51, found 39. The table is probably corrupted
2020-02-07T01:09:24.206740Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.db. The table is probably corrupted!
2020-02-07T01:09:24.206762Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.db. The table is probably corrupted!
2020-02-07T01:09:24.206799Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.tables_priv. The table is probably corrupted!
2020-02-07T01:09:24.206818Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.tables_priv. The table is probably corrupted!
2020-02-07T01:09:24.206834Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.tables_priv. The table is probably corrupted!
2020-02-07T01:09:24.206853Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.columns_priv. The table is probably corrupted!
2020-02-07T01:09:24.206876Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.columns_priv. The table is probably corrupted!
2020-02-07T01:09:24.206892Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.procs_priv. The table is probably corrupted!
2020-02-07T01:09:24.206912Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.procs_priv. The table is probably corrupted!
2020-02-07T01:09:24.206942Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.procs_priv. The table is probably corrupted!
2020-02-07T01:09:24.207159Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010316] [Server] Fatal error: Could not read the column 'authentication_string' from table 'mysql.user'. Please perform the MySQL upgrade procedure.
2020-02-07T01:09:24.207286Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010952] [Server] The privilege system failed to initialize correctly. For complete instructions on how to upgrade MySQL to a new version please see the 'Upgrading MySQL' section from the MySQL manual.
2020-02-07T01:09:24.208023Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2020-02-07T01:09:25.468177Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.17)  Source distribution.`

Comment: Try dump again but exclude the MySQL system database. Restoring users would be tricky but pt-show-grants can help

Answer (score 0):

You can't just copy the data files over. You have to dump the SQL from MySQL and then reimport it.

Here's a great tutorial on how to do this using the tools: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-import-and-export-databases-in-mysql-or-mariadb

Comment: This is the method that I used for moving the database. I will edit my question so it is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You are skipping 3 major releases.  It might be better to keep the last of them, 5.7.

That is,

1. Install 5.7
2. Load the 5.1 dump
3. Fix all the issues that come up
4. Upgrade in place to 8.0.

There are major "under-the-covers" things that changed going to 8.0.  But 8.0 understands coming erom 5.7 (but not from older versions).